# Unable to connect to ORACLE database using TOAD, but able to using SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, toad

I'm able to connect my organization's database server using SQL Plus.

```
sqlplus /nolog
sql> connect [username]/[password]@[servername]
Connected.
```

However, when I use TOAD for Oracle 10.6 - I'm unable to connect. It keeps saying "No Listener"

I'm not sure if I'm providing the right credentials under new connection. All I have is:
    servername,
    username,
    password

Not sure where it fits in the TOAD new connection screen. Any help?

Comment: How do you connect with SQL*Plus? Via TNS? Is your DB local on your machine or remote one? Maybe just post what you have after @ and content of `tnsnames.ora` for that server. And check where `TNS_ADMIN` variable points

Comment: In toad Try connect directly not with tns

Comment: lsnrctl status make sure your listener is up and accepting connections. Also make sure your database is actually up and running (e.g. select * from v$instance / v$database etc.). It won't allow remote logins in certain modes / states.